# Simultaneous double frame scrolling fails in FF on OSX and Win. w/ JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scroll

I'm trying to achieve a simultaneous menu/content scrolling, like on [www.urplay.se](http://www.urplay.se). The following code is very slow in Firefox (Win & OSX) but works in all other desktop browsers. Any idea how to improve in FF?

Update: Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/2rCPD/

Update: the problem only occurs when scrolling with a mouse. A macbook trackpad works fine. Also, the scrolling is only slow when both divs are scrolling. Try it in the fiddle: when the blue left content stops scrolling, the red right content starts to scroll at normal speed.

```
function initiateDoubleScroll() {
    $document.on('scroll.doubleScrollNameSpace', function () {
        $myMenu.scrollTop($document.scrollTop());
    });
    $myMenu.on('scroll.doubleScrollNameSpace', function () {
        $document.scrollTop($myMenu.scrollTop());
    });
}
```

$myMenu is the left side wrapper div (look at urplay.se). The wrapper div extends full window height and has "overflow-y: scroll".